# for loop issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a small problem with a simple loop in javascript and can't figure out the problem ! what am i missing ?

```
window.onload = function(){
    var linksToSlides = ["fischer","neotex","felo","safety","stella","boltsNuts"];
    for (var i=0;i < 6;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ goTo(linksToSlides[i]); });
        document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ goTo(linksToSlides[i]); });
        document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[i]); });
    }
};
```

it simply doesn't work... but the following code works without a loop.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var linksToSlides = ["fischer","neotex","felo","safety","stella","boltsNuts"];
    //header links to slides
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[0]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[1]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[2].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[2]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[3].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[3]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[4].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[4]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[5].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[5]);});

    //footer links to slides
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[0]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[1]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[2].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[2]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[3].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[3]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[4].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[4]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("footerSlideTo")[5].addEventListener("click", function(){goTo(linksToSlides[5]);});

    //menu links to slides
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[0]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[1].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[1]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[2].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[2]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[3].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[3]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[4].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[4]);});
    document.getElementsByClassName("menuLinks")[5].addEventListener("click", function(){closeMenu();goTo(linksToSlides[5]);});
};
```

i've also ran tests to see that `[i]` values are coming out right and that `linksToSlides[i]` are giving the good values and all seems fine.

all other loops in other functions work fine. Just this loop doesn't work !

Comment: i feel like this has something to do with closures

Comment: ReferenceError: pagesLocation is not defined
[Learn More]

Comment: so there's something else wrong with your code then..

Comment: please check is it undefined fbefore bind the event if(typeof document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[i] != 'undefined')
   document.getElementsByClassName("headerSlideTo")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ goTo(linksToSlides[i]); });

Comment: ReferenceError: pagesLocation is not defined [Learn More]  ---> this came from not a removed function request from someone else... isn't the problem.

Comment: i have no errors now in console and with FOR LOOP does not work and without FOR LOOP works just fine. I can simply leave it without the loop...won't be an issue... but why is the problem with the loop in the code .... and no console errors given.

Comment: arghhhhhh found the problem......  for (var i=0;i < 6;i++){   changed to for (let i=0;i < 6;i++){